# .netCore api gets the same parameter to controller every time from front end part which is Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

i have a very wierd problem,from my mutiselectbox i pick a value which should be sent to back end,first time i do it gets the value and works fine,but second,....value i pick from my multiselect i still get the first value in my back end:

```
get in average(ip){
url_avgWind="http://localhost:59628/api/Reports/avgWind";
console.log("here is my ip:"+ip);
 return this.http.post(this.url_avgWind,{},{params:{ipAddress:ip}});
```

}

in my back end which i get the same IP:

```
 [HttpPost]

    public IActionResult avgWind(string ipAddress)
    {

        var rslt = _windspd.avgWind(ipAddress);
        return Ok(rslt);
    }
```

the issue is my ipadress is the same everytime and does not change!any idea?

Comment: which browser ?

Comment: @pc_coder chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,first param is url, second param is body ,third param is options

to take last ip from array

```
var data=ip.length>0 ? ip[ip.length-1] : null;
```

then send this data rather than sending array

```
return this.http.post(this.url_avgWind,{ipAddress:data});
```

and use FromBody

```
public IActionResult avgWind([FromBody] IpAdress ip)

public class IpAdress{

   public string ipAddress {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: i get null in my controller

Comment: http://localhost:59628/api/Reports/avgWind 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: Did you put [FromBody] to core api  ?

Comment: the thing is why ipaddress is the same everyttime?!i log ipaddress and i see its changing but my controller always get the first ip address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215542/discussion-between-pc-coder-and-ilmagnifico).